# Put model associations calls from view to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

How can I put model associations calls from views to controllers in Rails 4 or later?

For example I have:

Model:

```
class Parent 
  has_many :children
end

class Child
end
```

Controller:

```
class ParentController < ApplicationController
  def index
     @parents = Parent.all
  end
end

class ChildrenController < ApplicationController
  def index
     @children = Parent.find(params[:parent_id]).children  
  end
end
```

View:

parents/index.html.erb

```
<% @parents.each do |parent| %>
   <% render parent.children %>
<% end %>
```

some partial children/_child.html.erb

```
<%= child.name %>
```

route.rb

```
resources :parents do
    resources :children
end
```

How can I substitute call of method `parent.children` by using somehow logic in controller - for example, ChildrenController::index method that requires url parameter?

I believe this will allow me to abstract view from model.

By abstraction I mean - if i change the model - for example, it won't have has_many association between parent and child - but still want to preserve the view then i will have only change the code in controller not in the view.

Further, i can extract the model logic in controller to some business class that will act like a model interface to use.

I am trying to build two-layered architecture with separated Presentation Layer (views, controllers) and Business layer (business classes, activerecords).

Probably this architecture could avoid the cases like with futurelearn portal that decided to split their STI model (single table) to several different ones. But having no real separation it became a creative task of tricking the Rails (see https://about.futurelearn.com/blog/refactoring-rails-sti). Code had a lot of association calls and it was necessary to develop smth to preserve these calls (only because otherwise it would be necessary to change too much code) and change model at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by

> I believe this will allow me to abstract view from model.

You are not using model in the view per se. You are using the ActiveRecord associations in the view which I think is the right way to do this sort of thing. Not sure if rendering all the children for each parent is the right thing to do as far as reading all those records in memory is concerned but that's a whole different topic.

FWIW, both `parent.children` and `Parent.find(params[:parent_id]).children` will generate the exact same SQL on the backend.

Comment: Hello, Chaitanya. Please see edited version of question - i added some explanation of what I mean at the end.

Comment: Probably i should ask in a separate question if two layered architecture is possible in Rails.

Comment: If you end up removing the `has_many` relationship, you can add a method `children` in your Parent model that will return the associated children. I prefer the ActiveRecord models to just do CRUD operations so I would probably move the children method to a concern if you want to keep the  `parent.children` call in the view. Alternatively, you can move it to a service object if you are fine with doing something like `parent.children =  children_of(parent_id)` in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

That is ok, if you have such a call in your view, i believe that there is no good way to remove it. The only thing you can do  - you can try to hide this call, but this will not bring you real abstraction.

But there are some things, that you need to do:
 1. Add `includes` to load your associations in a single query

```
def index
  @parents = Parent.includes(:children).all
end
```

2. If you don't need your parents in your view (it's not clear - do you only render children partial, or there are other lines in that view?), only children - you can just load your childrens :)

```
@children = Children.all
# or, if your children can be without parents
@children = Children.where.not(parent_id: nil).all
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you missed put `belongs_to`:

```
class Parent 
  has_many :children
end

class Child
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

Comment: i asked something different. Could you tell what is not clear in question. However, i think belongs_to should just create an option to use child.parent that i am not using in example anyway

Comment: Useful info but does not answer the question